# Equivalent of python lambda function for C (Python Extensions)

Tags: python, c, python-c-api, numerical-integration, python-extensions

I'v written a Python extension module with C to speed up computation times. The first step is a 2D integration of a function f(x,y,k), which is very fast and allows me to integrate over y in [y1(x),y2(x)] and x in [a,b] whilst assigning a float to k. But I really need to integrate k over the range [c,d]. Currently, I'm doing something like this in Python

```
inner = lambda k: calc.kernel(l,k,ki)
I = quad(inner,c,d)[0]
```

where calc is my C-extension module and calc.kernel calls gauss2 to perform 2D integration. l and ki are just other variables. But with my data, quad still takes many hours to finish. I would like to do all calculations within the C-extension module, but I'm really stumped on how to implement this outer integral. Here is my C-code

```
#include <Python.h>
#include <math.h>

double A96[96]={        /* abscissas for 96-point Gauss   quadrature */
    };

double W96[96]={            /* weights for 96-point Gauss quadrature */
    };

double Y1(double x){
    return 0;
    }

double Y2(double x){
    return x;
    }

double gauss1(double F(double),double a,double b)
{ /* 96-pt Gauss qaudrature integrates F(x) from a to b */
int i;
double cx,dx,q;
cx=(a+b)/2;
dx=(b-a)/2;
q=0;
for(i=0;i<48;i++)
    q+=W96[i]*(F(cx-dx*A96[i])+F(cx+dx*A96[i]));
return(q*dx);
}

double gauss2(double F(double,double,int,double,double),double Y1(double),double Y2(double),double a,double b,int l,double k, double ki)
{/* 96x96-pt 2-D Gauss qaudrature integrates
           F(x,y) from y=Y1(x) to Y2(x) and x=a to b */
int i,j,h;
double cx,cy,dx,dy,q,w,x,y1,y2;
cx=(a+b)/2;
dx=(b-a)/2;
q=0;
for(i=0;i<48;i++)
    {
    for(h=-1;h<=1;h+=2)
        {
        x=cx+h*dx*A96[i];
        y1=Y1(x);
        y2=Y2(x);
        cy=(y1+y2)/2;
        dy=(y2-y1)/2;
        w=dy*W96[i];
        for(j=0;j<48;j++)
            q+=w*W96[j]*(F(x,cy-dy*A96[j],l,k,ki)+F(x,cy+dy*A96[j],l,k,ki));
        }
    }
return(q*dx);
}

double ps_fact(double z){
    double M = 0.3;
    return 3/2*(M*(1+z)*(1+z)*(1+z) + (1-M))*(M*(1+z)*(1+z)*(1+z) + (1-M))*(M*(1+z)*(1+z)*(1+z) + (1-M))/(1+z)/(1+z);
    }
double drdz(double z){
    double M = 0.3;
    return 3000/sqrt(M*(1+z)*(1+z)*(1+z) + (1-M));
}

double rInt(double z){
    double M = 0.3;
    return 3000/sqrt(M*(1+z)*(1+z)*(1+z) + (1-M));
}

double kernel_func ( double y , double x, int l,double k, double ki) {
    return ps_fact(y)*ki*rInt(x)*sqrt(M_PI/2/rInt(x))*jn(l+0.5,ki*rInt(x))*drdz(x)*(rInt(x)-rInt(y))/rInt(y)*sqrt(M_PI/2/rInt(y))*jn(l+0.5,k*rInt(y))*drdz(y);
}

static PyObject* calc(PyObject* self, PyObject* args)
{
    int l;
    double k, ki;
    if (!PyArg_ParseTuple(args, "idd", &l, &k, &ki))
        return NULL;

    double res;
    res = gauss2(kernel_func,Y1, Y2, 0,10,l, k, ki);

    return Py_BuildValue("d", res);
}

static PyMethodDef CalcMethods[] = {
    {"kernel", calc, METH_VARARGS, "Calculates kernel values."},
    {NULL, NULL, 0, NULL}
};

PyMODINIT_FUNC initcalc(void){
    (void) Py_InitModule("calc", CalcMethods);
```

A96 and W96 both contain the points for the Gaussian quadrature, so don't worry that they are empty here. I should add I don't take any credit for the functions gauss1 and gauss2.

EDIT: python code was wrong - edited now.

Comment: Integration is a wrong tag here - please take time to read the tag descriptions.

Comment: what have you tried? where does the quad function come from? how about [monte carlo integration](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monte_Carlo_integration)

Comment: @Julius the first code block is python calling scipy.integrate.quad. Using quad to integrate the inner integral works, but is still slow for the limits I'm using. Thank you for monte carlo, I'll look into that as a possible option, but the C code is so fast over the inner integral, I'm sure if I could figure out how to do this in C it will be very useful in the future.

Comment: it's already in Fortran https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v0.17.0/scipy/integrate/quadpack.py#L45-L360

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the source code for scipy integrate quad is a good place to start if you haven't looked there : https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v0.17.0/scipy/integrate/quadpack.py#L45-L360

Looks like most of the work is already being done by native Fortran code, which is normally either as fast or faster than C/C++ code. You will be hard pressed to improve on that, unless you create/find a CUDA implementation.

You make the Fortran code multithreaded, if it's not already and the source is open. Lastly, you could make a threading dispatcher in C/Fortran  (python doesn't support real threading because of the GIL) and just make your calls to quad parallel from one another atleast. Interfacing calc directly with Fortran quad would probably save you some decent overhead too.

Comment: Thanks, I have written a pure python implementation using quad and dblquad, but this takes days (probably over a week) to run and I'm limited to 5 days max mainframe time. It is clear from comparing just the inner integral the C-extension module is orders of magnitude faster. I would like to rewrite the extension mod so that calc.gauss1 can integrate over calc.gauss2, thus replacing all integration in python, but I'm limited in my coding skills.

Comment: Ok, I'v just seen your edit. I'll look into multithreading, but again that's something I have no experience with.

Comment: it's pretty simple http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/thread/thread/ just remember if you pass pointers that threads share out of function memory space